# CMake dependency in a project

Tags: configuration, cmake, installation

I am working on a project that depends on CMake. When I download CMake and I add it to the root of the repo I still have the same error.

```
CMake is a pre-requisite to build this repository but it was not found on the path.
Please install CMake from http://www.cmake.org/download/ and ensure it is on your path.
```

Where and how should I add CMake to the project?

Comment: You need to **install** CMake, not just to download it. Follow description on the download page, corresponded to installation file you have downloaded.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev. But when I try to install that it blinks and nothing else happens. Also when it says install to your path what are they referring to?

Comment: `install to your path` means that you may choose directory where (roughly) installed files will be located. By default, files are installed into OS-specific location, and this is sufficient in the most cases. BTW, you don't describe neither a file with CMake you have downloaded, nor OS on which you work. It is difficult to suggest something without this information.

Comment: My environment is Windows 64 bit, and when I click on the exe that is in the bin folder it just disappear. Also is it fair to say that the path is the root folder of the program I would like to run? Thanks Tsyvarev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't know what you mean by *repo*, after searching for the error message

```
CMake is a pre-requisite to build this repository but it was not found on the path.
```

It seems you are working with **dotnet/corefx** or an older version of **dotnet/coreclr**.

Indeed, it looks like a problem similar to yours has been fixed on May 30, see commit entitled `Improve CMake detection on Windows when not in PATH` here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/28799